# Is this a simple debounce function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var debounce = function(fn,delay){
    var timeoutId;
    return function debounced(){
        if(timeoutId){
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
        timeoutId = setTimeout(fn.bind(this),delay,arguments);
    }
}
```

Is the above function a simple way of debouncing ? I want to know if its correctly implemented or not . Are there any flaws ?

Comment: An obvious question: does it work?

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there any flaws?

Yes. The `setTimeout` function doesn't take an `arguments` array as a third parameter. It can take more than two arguments, but those are despised since they're not backwards-compatible with legacy engines. Read on [`setTimeout` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout). So better go with

```
var that = this,
    args = arguments;
timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    fn.apply(that, args);
}, delay);
```

Comment: @zerkms: Those few lines to replace the `timeoutId = setTimeout(fn.bind(this),delay,arguments);` assignment of course… I just didn't want to repeat the whole function.

Comment: Makes sense, sorry, +1