# How to slowdown/debounce events handling with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, debouncing

Handle scroll event will fire to often. What is the way to slowdown/debounce it?
And if it's possible, i want last event always be fired and not skipped.

```
  const handleScroll = event => {
    //how to debounse scroll change?
    //if you will just setValue here, it's will lag as hell on scroll
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    }
  }, [])
```

Here is the useDebounce hook example from [xnimorz](https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const useDebounce = (value, delay) => {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value)

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const handler = setTimeout(() => {
        setDebouncedValue(value)
      }, delay)

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(handler)
      }
    },
    [value, delay]
  )

  return debouncedValue
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Event handler that uses hooks can be debounced done the same way as any other function with any debounce implementation, e.g. Lodash:

```
  const updateValue = _.debounce(val => {
    setState(val);
  }, 100);

  const handleScroll = event => {
    // process event object if needed
    updateValue(...);
  }
```

Notice that due to how React synthetic events work, `event` object needs to be processed synchronously if it's used in event handler.

> last event always be fired and not skipped

It's expected that only the last call is taken into account with debounced function, unless the implementation allows to change this, e.g. `leading` and `trailing` options in [Lodash `debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce).

Comment: So i need Lodash library for this _.debounce to work? Is there a way without external library?

Comment: You will need to write this functionality yourself. At this point this isn't specific to React or hooks. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695334/is-this-a-simple-debounce-function-in-javascript . This is not a productive way to do things because this is what libraries exist for. FWIW, Lodash implementation offers much better performance than naive setTimeout implementation.

Comment: if you don't want to import lodash entirely you can just use this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce

Comment: why do you use 100? can you explain?

Comment: @Flezcano It's random number, just enough to prevent it from being triggered 10s times per second but small enough to be nearly instant

Answer (score 1):

```js
const debounceLoadData = useCallback(debounce((debounceValue)=>{  
    props.setSenderAddress(debounceValue)
}, 300), []);
```

Comment: Where did you get the debounce function?